# Webview inside Broadcastreceiver

Tags: android

I make my first steps with android app development. Wanted to create an app which connects to a website, fills out a form and checks the result after submit. This procedure is executed as a broadcast receiver every 24h.

Because this page is using javascript I used webview. But I think because of the asynchronous behavior of webview, the broadcast receiver object is killed before the page loaded for the first time.

Inside the onReceive method I create a new webview object. To the webview I add a JavascriptInterface so that I can get the content from the page to parse for success or failure. And onPageFinished calls a member method of the broadcast receiver which starts the form filling process.

As far as I understand this, while the webview is loading the page, the execution flow will leave the onReceive method. After this the broadcast receiver is killed and with it also the webview which will never finish loading the page.

I was thinking about waiting for a special event before leaving the onReceive method. But I don't know if this is the best solution and how I could achieve this.

Thanks in advance and all the best
r2p2

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you shouldn't even be able to display a WebView in a Broadcast Receiver's context since it is not a UI context.

The cleanest way to implement your idea would be to have your Receiver launch an Activity, which then dismisses itself when your WebView work is done.

However, if you don't need user interaction with the WebView, you should look into creating a Web Service for yourself and using raw HTTP requests to retrieve, fill out, submit and validate your form.

Comment: I don't want to display the webview. But I can't do the raw HTTP stuff because the page uses JS to generate/or load a key needed for the authentication process.

Launching a new Activity sounds good. Do they spawn in foreground?

Comment: @r2p2 Yeah they spawn in the foreground.

Comment: Then I will set it on the possible solution list. But I would prefer not to interrupt the user. Just wanted to communicate over the notifications bar (success or failure).